# How to check if one text files with same name and extension is present in two different folders in python?

Tags: python-2.7, directory, text-files

Like i've text files with same names in two folder, one folder has input text files and the other one has the output text files. but the name of both input and output files are exactly the same. So if i want to check how many files are there with exact names and extensions?

```
import os

filename1 = os.path.basename('/home/Desktop/iput_2d_spectra/*.ares') 
filename2 = os.path.basename('/home/Desktop/output_2d_spectra/*.ares')

if filename1 == filename2:
   print(filename1,filename2)
else:
   None
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try `os.listdir()` to get the contents of both directories, and then compare the resulting lists to produce the duplicate entries.

One example, untested:

```
duplicate_fns = [x for x in os.listdir(input_path) if x.endswith(ext) if x in os.listdir(output_path)]
```

This is not an efficient solution, by the way.

Comment: Nah i just tried that and it's giving the expected error "No such file or directory".

Comment: Sorry maybe I’m not understanding your code then. Are you getting “No such file...” for the path above with a regex in it?

Comment: yeah there are two folders and the path defined in code is correct but still i got this error.

Comment: @astroluv If os.listdir()produces that error then the path is invalid. You should call os.listdir on the path, not the file name. This would produce a list for each path, and you can compare the two lists. Also: your path for filename 1 has no “n” in “input”. Is that intentional?

Comment: Ahh.. i think i realized my mistake because "*.ares" is the file extension that's why it's giving the error.!

Comment: how can i compare two lists having files with same extensions??

Comment: @astroluv I posted a possible solution above. Warning: I punched it into my phone so it might have an error. Basically you filter one or both lists to contain only the entries ending with your desired extension, then filter again for entries that are in both lists.

Comment: As the input_path and output_path are lists so we had to convert them to string first. But it gave the error "Not a directory: 'Moon-2016-03-23T02:33:28.352.ares'". I don't know what to do now

Comment: I assumed `input_path` is `/home/Desktop/iput_2d_spectra/`, `output_path` is  `/home/Desktop/output_2d_spectra/` and `ext` is `ares`. So the example I gave is complete once they are defined.